# Support of PostgreSQL specific array_agg function in scala frameworks?

Tags: postgresql, scala, slick, anorm, squeryl

Is there some scala relational database framework (anorm, squeryl, etc...) using postgres-like aggregators to produce lists after a group-by, or at least simulating its use?

I would expect two levels of implementation:

- a "standard" one, where at least any SQL grouping with array_agg is translated to a List of the type which is being aggregated,
- and a "scala ORM powered" one where some type of join is allowed so that if the aggregation is a foreign key to other table, a List of elements of the other table is produced. Of course this last thing is beyond the reach of SQL, but if I am using a more powerful language, I do not mind some steroids.

I find specially intriguing that the documentation of slick, which is based precisely in allowing scala group-by notation, seems to negate explicitly the output of lists as a result of the group-by.

### EDIT: use case

You have the typical many-to-many table of, say, products and suppliers, pairs (p_id, s_id). You want to produce a list of suppliers for each product. So the postgresql query should be

```
SELECT p_id, array_agg(s_id) from t1 group by p_id
```

One could expect some idiomatic way to to this in slick, but I do not see how. Furthermore, if we go to some ORM, then we could also consider the join with the tables products and suppliers, on p_id and s_id respectively, and get as answer a zip (product, (supplier1, supplier2, supplierN)) containing the objects and not only the ids

Comment: By the way. even without aggregation, the option to interpret a foreign key as a reference to other object should be a welcome plus.

Comment: Result of `array_agg` is of type `Array` in JDBC, so using Anorm you can parse such column as either `Array[T]` or `List[T]`, provided each value of the array is of a supported type that can be parsed as `T`. Slick should have something similar with its native query.

Comment: What I was thinking is that Slick could add some syntax do to this. They keept telling that .group-by must always be terminated by a map plus and aggregator (say, avg) in order to avoid the production of Lists. But in postgresql it is natural to produce lists, so an "unaggregated group-by query"  in Slick should/could compile to array_agg

Comment: It's a kind of case where I prefer to handle DB specificity with a custom result parser (Anorm).

Answer (score 2):

I am also not sure if I understand you question correct, could you elaborate?

In slick you currently can not use postgres "array_agg" or "string_agg" as a method on type Query. If you want to use this specific function then you need to use custom sql. But: I added an issue some time ago (https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/923, you should follow this discussion) and we have a prototype from cvogt ready for this.

I needed to use "string_agg" in the past and added a patch for it (see https://github.com/mobiworx/slick/commit/486c39a7ed90c9ccac356dfdb0e5dc5c24e32d63), so maybe this is helpful to you. Look at "AggregateTest" to learn more about it.

Another possibility is to encapsulate the usage of "array_agg" in a database view and just use this view with slick. This way you do not need "array_agg" directly in slick.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [slick-pg](https://github.com/tminglei/slick-pg).

It [supports](https://github.com/tminglei/slick-pg/tree/master/core/src/main/scala/com/github/tminglei/slickpg/agg) `array_agg` and other aggregate functions.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is intriguing, care to elaborate a little on how it might ideally look? When you `group by` you often have an additional column, such as count(*) over and above the standard columns from your case class, so what would the type of your List be?

Most of my (anorm) methods either return a singleton (perhaps Option) or a List of that class's type. For each case class, I have an `sqlFields` variable (e.g. `m.id, m.name, m.forManufacturer`) and a single parser variable that I reference as either `.as(modelParser.singleOpt)` or `.as(modelParser *)`. For foreign keys, a `lazy val` at the case class level (or def if it needs to be) is pretty useful. E.g. if I had Model and Manufacturer entities, with a foreign key `forManufacturer` on Model, then I might define a `lazy val manufacturer : Manufacturer = ...` in the case class of the model, so that at any time I can refer to `model.manufacturer`. I can define joins as their own methods, either in this way, or as methods in the companion object.

Not 100% sure I am answering your question, but thought this was a bit long for a comment.

Edit: If your driver supported parsing of postgresql arrays, you could map them directly to a class like `ProductSuppliers(id:Int, suppliers:List[Int])` (or even `List[Supplier]`?) In anorm that's about as idiomatic as one could get, I think? For databases that don't support it, it seems to me similar to an `order by` version, i.e. `select p1, s1 from t1 order by p1`, which you could `groupBy p1` and similarly map to ProductSuppliers.

Comment: Really I do not know how sql-standard is the array_agg function, are you familiar with it? The additional column is converted to a list. Now, in slick and probably in anorm, I'd just expect a way to produce such lists and no more. In a ORM framework, if the type of the list was a foreign key to other table, I would expect the list to be converted in a list of objects of the other table.