# Slick 3.0 Array Aggregation Alternative

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

There is already a topic about array aggregation found here:

[Support of PostgreSQL specific array_agg function in scala frameworks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019021/support-of-postgresql-specific-array-agg-function-in-scala-frameworks)

However, since it's not currently supported, I'm finding it hard to do a few things with slick. Heres an simple example.

Say for example, that I run a business hosting parties.
Each party there are guests, hosts:

```
Party(id: Option[Int], name: String)
Guest(id: Option[Int], name: String)
Host(id: Option[Int], name: String)

PartyGuests(partyId, guestId: Int)
PartyHosts(partyId, hostId: Int)
```

And I want a table of all the parties, displaying all the guests and hosts like this:

```
PartyId     |Guests                 |Hosts
------------|-----------------------|------
1           |Adam, Julie, Jack      |Tom, Jamie, John
2           |Joe, Jim, Jake         |Tom, Tony, James
3           |Amy, Sally             |Jenny
```

My solutions is this:

```
// The map is: partyId -> (guestNamesList, hostNamesList)
val partyTable: Map[Int, (List[String], List[String])] = (for {
  party <- db.run(parties.result.list)
  guest <- db.run(partyGuests
    .filter(_.partyId === party.id)
    .flatMap(_.guest)
    .result.list)
  host <- db.run(partyHosts
    .filter(_.partyId === party.id)
    .flatMap(_.host)
    .result.list)
} yield (party, guest, host))
  .groupBy { case (party, guest, host) =>
    party.id
  }
  .mapValues { values =>
    val myGuests = values.map(_._2).distinct.map(_.name)
    val myHosts = values.map(_._3).distinct.map(_.name)
    (myGuests, myHosts)
  }
```

However this solution is very space consuming on large data sets. Does anyone know of a better solution?